# Cannot read property scrollIntoView of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, mobile

I have this function in my React component to scroll to this particular element using a `ref`.

```
 scrollToIntroVideo = () => {
    this.myRef.current.scrollIntoView();
  };
```

This works fine when I'm on desktop but when I'm on a smaller viewport like on mobile, it gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null

In my class component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
```

Here's where I access it:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
    if (this.props.params === "foo") {
      this.scrollToIntroVideo();
    }
  }
```

Any idea why this won't work?

Comment: Where did you init your ref, put to element prop and when did you try to access?

Comment: Please check above.

Comment: You should use a regular function while working with the `this` keyword because it always represents the object that defined the arrow function. In your case, it would be your javascript file. In the case of the regular function,  the `this` keyword represented the object that is called the function.

Though I am not sure of it. Give it a try.

Comment: @vaibhavdeep can you add here a minimal reproduction of your issue?